# How do I create an asp.net web page/site project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate in Windows 8.

I'm confused as to how to start an asp.net web page web site. Is it via Visual Studio, by selecting File | New Website | ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v2) or (some other selection) or do I need to create the asp.net web page web site from WebMatrix and, if so, do I need to install WebMatrix separately from Visual Studio, or was it installed as a part of Visual Studio?

Searching for the existence of an app named "WebMatrix" in Windows 8 returned nothing...

### UPDATE

Mike, I'm a third of the way through your book and I think it's great.

A couple of nights ago I read where you called braces brackets or vice versa and almost said out loud, "This cat must be a Brit!" I then read the frontispiece where that exact fact is declaimed.

Anyway, I was reading "C# 5.0 in a Nuts Hell" today at lunch, and read: (a llittle context: the Albahari boys are here discussing asp.net MVC) "*What you lose over Web Forms is a designer. This makes Web Forms still a good choice for web pages with predominantly static content.*" (bottom of page 194).

This ("predominantly static content") describes the site I'm going to build to a T: most of the content will be static or simple links to other sites. The only non-static content will be pushpins on a Bing Map, but even these could be viewed as static (depending on one's definition of static), as they will really remain the same superset - the user just selects which subset they want to see at any given time.

The "static electricity" voltage of my site depends also on whether you call a PayPal button, a Twitter window, and rotating Ads to be static, too, I reckon.

Anyway, I said all that to say this: In my situation, would Web FORMS be better than Web PAGES? Pardon me if the rest of your book answers that question, but ... I'm not the most patient cat in the world.

Comment: Haven't done it myself, but it seems like its the razor v2, pretty detailed example is here : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/Asp-Net-web-pages-with-visual-studio-2012/

Comment: In response to your update, if your site doesn't need a database, you don't need ASP.NET at all. You can achieve all you describe through simple HTML and Javascript, and the end result (with .html files) will be cheaper to host. And I don't feel inclined to agree with the quote you pulled from the other book, which I don't have so I don't know the full context it is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebMatrix is an IDE - not a development framework. The development framework that it was primarily designed to support is known as the ASP.NET Web Pages framework. However, within Visual Studio, it is known as an ASP.NET Web Site (Razor vx) and as you have discovered is accessible via the New Web Site option.

You do not need to install WebMatrix in order to develop these types of applications. However, WebMatrix offers more choice in terms of templates for Web Pages sites and starts up a lot quicker than VS. On the other hand, WebMatrix doesn't include any debugging tools.

WebMatrix is completely separate from Visual Studio and is not installed with it. If you want to install WebMatrix, you can get it here: http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Comment: Thanks, Mike; I ordered the book by you and Spaanjaars yesterday. I guess I'll find out when I get the book, but since WebMatrix doesn't have any debugging tools, how do you debug projects created with WebMatrix - by opening the project in VS? IOW, is WebMatrix to VS what Blend is to VS (sort of)?

Comment: The Web Pages framework includes an ObjectInfo helper that features a Print method. It outputs details of hte object passed in so you can examine its properties and their values. Otherwise you can launch a Visual Studio from within WebMatrix and it will open with the current web site.

Comment: So is there any advantage to using WebMatrix over VS 2012 for creating these ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v2) projects? All things being equal, I'd prefer to use VS, as I'm familiar with that. I'll still read your book, though - should arrive Saturday, amazon says.

Comment: The main reason I create Web Pages sites in WebMatrix is to make use of the templates, and to manage SQL Compact databases through the database management tools it has built in. Oh - and it opens in a fraction of the time that it takes VS to crank itself into life. Then I forget myself and continue to code in WebMatrix. I usually open the site in VS (Express) if I need to use Paste From VS in Windows Live Writer to generate colour-coded HTML for a blog article, or if I need to do some in-depth debugging.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer to the question, but I just started using WebMatrix and it seems much easier and convenient to use mostly because of the various templates available.